# Working with rar files

Tags: rar

I have a directory full of rar files, with extensions ranging from `.r00` to `.r30`. It also has one file with `.rar` extension.

From all of this must come a video file. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have `rar` program, the command `x` would accomplish the task:

```
rar x <part_name>
```

The program automatically searches for the appropriate parts of the archive.

Note: sometimes the naming can be `<archive_name>.part##.rar`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `unrar` program. From [how-to-open-a-rar-file-in-linux](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-open-a-rar-file-in-linux):

> If you need to uncompress a .rar archive in Linux, you can download a program called unrar. If you are using Ubuntu or Debian, you can install unrar by opening a terminal and typing sudo apt-get install unrar. Then read the instructions by typing man unrar.
>
> [UPDATE: to install unrar in Ubuntu you need the Multiverse Repository enabled.]
>
> Basically, to unrar a file in Linux, just navigate to the directory where your rar archive is and type unrar x [filename.rar], replacing [filename.rar] with the name of your rar archive.

For a series of files, you should be able to just specify the one with the `.rar` extension.

**Update** - this is confirmed by [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Unrar-Files-in-Linux):

> If a RAR file is broken into smaller files, they are named .rar, .r00, .r01 and so on. Point your unrar utility at the .rar file and it will automatically put the pieces back together.